# Rails: rescue an unsuccessful sass compression (asset pipeline)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I precompile a lot of css files (even the one I have in the vendor directory).
I have problem precompiling some css with this code

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0,startColorstr='#fff2f2f2',endColorstr='#ffcccccc')}
```

I want to implement a custom compressor that will try to compress the file or do no compression if an error occur

I implemented this class on config/production.rb

```
class TrySassCompression
  def compress(string)
    begin
      compressor = Sass::Rails::CssCompressor.new
      compressor.compress(string)
    rescue
      #No compression
    end
  end
end
```

and in the config block:

```
  config.assets.css_compressor = TrySassCompression.new
```

But it does not work.
I do not know how to explicitly call the sass-rails compressor

I get this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for nil:NilClass
/Users/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@allsquare/gems/sprockets-3.0.0.beta.6/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:141:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/Users/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@allsquare/gems/sprockets-3.0.0.beta.6/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:89:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/Users/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@allsquare/gems/sprockets-3.0.0.beta.6/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:27:in `load'
```

My config:

```
config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'templates')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'json')
config.assets.precompile << "emoji/**/*.png"
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf *.otf *.html *.json)
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement what you want, but from the `sass-rails` changelog on June 24, 2013 they say: `Remove Sass::Rails::Compressor. Use Sprockets::SassCompressor (:sass option) instead`

Comment: I get this result:  

2.0.0-p598 :001 > compressor = Sprockets::SassCompressor.new
 => #<Sprockets::SassCompressor:0x007fcedce00440 @options={}, @cache_key=["SassCompressor", "3.4.10 (Selective Steve)", "1", {}]>  

2.0.0-p598 :002 > compressor.compress("tkozkoktz")
NoMethodError: undefined method `compress' for #<Sprockets::SassCompressor:0x007fcedce00440>